# Convergence of series involving Euler's totient function.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have to show that if $\phi$ is Euler's totient function, then the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\phi (n) \log n}$ diverges and $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\phi(n) \log^2 n}$ converges, but there's something I don't understand.

We know both $\phi$ and $\log$ go off to infinity. So shouldn't they both converge?

And what about the series: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (n) \log n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (n) \log^2 n}$, where $\pi$ is the function that counts the prime numbers up to n?

It is easy to check that the first does not converge using that $\pi (n) \leq C \frac{n}{log n}$ for some positive constant $C$ but $\pi (n)$ also goes off to infinity. So is there a result analogue to this that would give the desired result for $\phi$?

Comment: Is $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$ finite or infinite? Knowing that helps answering the $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\phi(n)\log n}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi(n)\log^2 n}$ questions. For $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\phi(n)\log^2 n}$, we need something else.

Comment: Thanks, Could you be a bit more clear? So we know $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges, then how does that help?

Comment: $n>\phi(n)$. Can you take the first one from here?

Comment: For divergence of the first, Comparison Test. For the second, we need bounds on the growth rate of $\varphi$. One can quote the standard one, that involves $\log\log$ and Euler's $\gamma$, though one could use weaker bounds.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_of_the_function

Comment: Note that $\sum \dfrac{1}{nlog^2(n)}$ is convergent, which immediately tells you why the second sum is convergent.

Comment: @LandonCarter: Not quite, since $\phi(n)<n$ for $n>1.$ You need to show $\phi(n)$ isn't too small.

Comment: Ok, so I think got it. Correct me if I'm wrong. So using the bound for the growth of $\varphi$ as suggested by André, we obtain $ \frac{1}{\varphi \log ^2 (n)} \leq e^{\gamma} \frac{\log\log n }{n \log ^2 n} + \frac{ \frac{c}{\log\log n} }{n \log ^2 n} $ Then the series in the right side converges as Landon pointed out.